# iOS 10 Rich Media Push Notification (Media Attachment) in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I want to add Media especially images and videos in iOS 10 Push notification but images are not working in push. How to do that in Objective-C? My Code is as follows:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" )) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else{
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
        {
            if( !error ) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
                NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
            } else {
                NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
                NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
                NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
            }
        }];
    }
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as per need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
     NSLog(@"Device Token is \n%@",token);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO( @"10.0" )) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result){}];
    } else {
        /// previous stuffs for iOS 9 and below. I've shown an alert wth received data.
    }
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // iOS 10 will handle notifications through other methods

    if( NOTIFY_VISITORS_SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO( @"10.0" ) )
    {
        NSLog( @"iOS version >= 10. Let NotificationCenter handle this one." );
        // set a member variable to tell the new delegate that this is background
        return;
    }
    NSLog( @"HANDLE PUSH, didReceiveRemoteNotification: %@", userInfo );
    // custom code to handle notification content
    if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog( @"INACTIVE" );
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );
    }
    else if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground )
    {  
        NSLog( @"BACKGROUND" );  
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        NSLog( @"FOREGROUND" );  
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );  
    }  
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
    NSLog( @"Handle push from foreground" );
    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    NSLog(@"%@", notification.request.content.userInfo);
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSLog( @"Handle push from background or closed" );
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
    NSLog(@"%@", response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
```

Then I've added a new target **Notification Service Extension** as following:

**NotificationService.h**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@interface NotificationService : UNNotificationServiceExtension
@end
```

**NotificationService.m**

```
#import "NotificationService.h"

@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    // Modify the notification content here...
    //self.bestAttemptContent.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]", self.bestAttemptContent.body];

    // check for media attachment, example here uses custom payload keys mediaUrl and mediaType
    NSDictionary *userInfo = request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo == nil) {
        [self contentComplete];
        return;
    }

    NSString *mediaUrl = userInfo[@"mediaUrl"];
    NSString *mediaType = userInfo[@"mediaType"];

    if (mediaUrl == nil || mediaType == nil) {
        [self contentComplete];
        return;
    }

    // load the attachment
    [self loadAttachmentForUrlString:mediaUrl
                            withType:mediaType
                   completionHandler:^(UNNotificationAttachment *attachment) {
                       if (attachment) {
                           self.bestAttemptContent.attachments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:attachment];
                       }
                       [self contentComplete];
                   }];

}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    [self contentComplete];
}

- (void)contentComplete {
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

- (NSString *)fileExtensionForMediaType:(NSString *)type {
    NSString *ext = type;

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        ext = @"jpg";
    }

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
        ext = @"mp4";
    }

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"audio"]) {
        ext = @"mp3";
    }

    return [@"." stringByAppendingString:ext];
}

- (void)loadAttachmentForUrlString:(NSString *)urlString withType:(NSString *)type completionHandler:(void(^)(UNNotificationAttachment *))completionHandler  {

    __block UNNotificationAttachment *attachment = nil;
    NSURL *attachmentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *fileExt = [self fileExtensionForMediaType:type];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session downloadTaskWithURL:attachmentURL
                completionHandler:^(NSURL *temporaryFileLocation, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                    } else {
                        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                        NSURL *localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[temporaryFileLocation.path stringByAppendingString:fileExt]];
                        [fileManager moveItemAtURL:temporaryFileLocation toURL:localURL error:&error];

                        NSError *attachmentError = nil;
                        attachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"" URL:localURL options:nil error:&attachmentError];
                        if (attachmentError) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", attachmentError.localizedDescription);
                        }
                    }
                    completionHandler(attachment);
                }] resume];
}
@end
```

and my Notification Service Extension **Info.plist** is:
[image: Notification Service Extension Info.plist]

And I'm using php Script to send push notification as follows:

**TestPush.php**

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
  $deviceToken = 'my device tocken goes here';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'mypassphase';
// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Test iOS 10 Media Attachment Push';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
     'mutable-content' => 1,
     'category'=> "pusher"
    );
$body['data'] = array(
    'mediaUrl' => "http://www.alphansotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Push-notification-1.jpg",
    'mediaType' => "jpg"
);
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Sharing Images and file are hosted on server and push will send its link to show it.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Hello I am trying to implement this on Objective-C as well but can't find any resources online... Would you be able to share your code and/or a link to a resource that you used? Thanks!

Comment: The above code is working fine only audio and video not working in that. Just need to change payload format see in the 1st answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673707/ios-10-rich-media-push-notification-media-attachment-in-objective-c?noredirect=1#comment67813533_39673707).and if you find any solution for supporting audio and video please refer me that solution also.

Comment: I have implemented the code above and the payload but its not fully working, I think it has something to do with the info.plist because I can't see the Key Names in your screen shot.

Comment: It is the **info.plist** of **NotificationServiceExtension** part and the sourcecode is:
`<key>NSExtension</key>
 <dict><key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
   <key>UNNotificationExtensionCategory</key>
   <string>myCat</string>
   <key>UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio</key>
   <real>0.7</real>
   <key>UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden</key>
   <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>
  <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
  <string>NotificationService</string>
 </dict>
`

Comment: And there is a key `UNNotificationExtensionCategory` in this plist it is not being used in my code for ow but I think it is required in audio and video support.I am trying to do it and I'll update you when I get the solution.Kindly updte me if you able to resolve the issues. Thanks !!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still unable to get this working :(. didReceiveNotificationRequest in NotificationService is never called...

Comment: So I finally go this working, was an issue with my notification payload. I am now having a problem with the notification image being cropped. To fix this i read you have to pass through an option to the image attachment. I also read that you have to do the same thing for videos... For videos the option key is UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailTimeKey. But how do we pass options through?

Comment: what is : NOTIFY_VISITORS_SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO

I have error : Implecit call a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code is ok, it just expects a different push notification data format:

Try replacing this part:

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
     'mutable-content' => 1,
     'category'=> "pusher"
    );
$body['data'] = array(
    'mediaUrl' => "http://www.alphansotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Push-notification-1.jpg",
    'mediaType' => "jpg"
);
```

with:

```
$body = array(
  'aps' => array(
    'alert' => 'Rich notification',
    'sound' => 'default',
    'mutable-content' => 1
  ),
  'mediaUrl'  => 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG',
  'mediaType' => 'image'
);
```

Please note, that image should be accessible via `https://`

Comment: It is working but I'm unable to play youtube video while I have given embed code link. I want to update my code that should support all image, video and audio format.

Comment: I want to play video in push but it is not supporting in above code how to do that can you help me to play video from above code.

Comment: @Ashraf can you provide any sample demo links to know about the usage and project creation for the rich push notifications??

Comment: to see demo of Rich Media Attachment in Push notification [see this link](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-send-ios-10-notifications-using-the-push-notifications-api/)

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 11):

Additional caveat for this **not to work** is having the **Notification Service** 
`Deployment Target` value that's **not supported by your test device.**

In my case the Notification Service template had automatically set its `Deployment Target` to `10.2` while my test device is `10.1`

I wasted hours configuring my extension setup while its already working all along!

Comment: Caught by this too.

Comment: this helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: super bro. saved a day.