# We want to show Image with Push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Please give us suggestion, How to add image getting by notification in user notification like below image:

[image]

Or

[image]

Comment: rich notification ... search for it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839171/how-to-display-image-in-ios-push-notification                        try this

Comment: Try watching the two WWDC 2016 videos on notifications.

Comment: Hello guys, I have tried to use this code but when i added nsextension on info.plist and run my code than my screen is black. and send the notification from backend it can't work for me...please help

Comment: Thanks.. code is work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This two links may help:

[rich notifications](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/261-rich-notifications)

[iOS 10 Rich Media Push Notification (Media Attachment) in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673707/ios-10-rich-media-push-notification-media-attachment-in-objective-c)

Comment: Hello guys, I have tried to use this code but when i added nsextension on info.plist and run my code than my screen is black. and send the notification from backend it can't work for me...please help

Comment: Thanks.. code is work fine