# Display image in notification bar with remote notification(Rich media push notification) in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios10, usernotifications

I have integrated APNS and want to display image in remote notification like below;

[image]

I have used below code with reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673707/ios-10-rich-media-push-notification-media-attachment-in-objective-c);

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     [self registerForRemoteNotification];
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
     UIViewController *vc1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainscreen"];
     self.window.rootViewController = vc1;
     return YES;
}

- (void)registerForRemoteNotification 
{
        if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
            center.delegate = self;
            [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){

                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            }];
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{

            DeviceToken = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]];
            NSLog(@"Device Token = %@",DeviceToken);
    }
```

Then, I have created new target with **UNNotificationServiceExtension**  and created new bundle id "com.RichPush.app.Service-Extension" , I have also created new certificate and provision profile with above bundle for UNNotificationServiceExtension.

**NotificationService.h**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@interface NotificationService : UNNotificationServiceExtension
@end
```

**NotificationService.m**

```
#import "NotificationService.h"

@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    // Modify the notification content here...
    //self.bestAttemptContent.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]", self.bestAttemptContent.body];

    // check for media attachment, example here uses custom payload keys mediaUrl and mediaType
    NSDictionary *userInfo = request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo == nil) {
        [self contentComplete];
        return;
    }

    NSString *mediaUrl = userInfo[@"mediaUrl"];
    NSString *mediaType = userInfo[@"mediaType"];

    if (mediaUrl == nil || mediaType == nil) {
        [self contentComplete];
        return;
    }

    // load the attachment
    [self loadAttachmentForUrlString:mediaUrl
                            withType:mediaType
                   completionHandler:^(UNNotificationAttachment *attachment) {
                       if (attachment) {
                           self.bestAttemptContent.attachments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:attachment];
                       }
                       [self contentComplete];
                   }];

}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    [self contentComplete];
}

- (void)contentComplete {
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

- (NSString *)fileExtensionForMediaType:(NSString *)type {
    NSString *ext = type;

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        ext = @"jpg";
    }
   return [@"." stringByAppendingString:ext];
}

- (void)loadAttachmentForUrlString:(NSString *)urlString withType:(NSString *)type completionHandler:(void(^)(UNNotificationAttachment *))completionHandler  {

    __block UNNotificationAttachment *attachment = nil;
    NSURL *attachmentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *fileExt = [self fileExtensionForMediaType:type];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session downloadTaskWithURL:attachmentURL
                completionHandler:^(NSURL *temporaryFileLocation, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                    } else {
                        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                        NSURL *localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[temporaryFileLocation.path stringByAppendingString:fileExt]];
                        [fileManager moveItemAtURL:temporaryFileLocation toURL:localURL error:&error];

                        NSError *attachmentError = nil;
                        attachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"" URL:localURL options:nil error:&attachmentError];
                        if (attachmentError) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", attachmentError.localizedDescription);
                        }
                    }
                    completionHandler(attachment);
                }] resume];
}
@end
```

I used below plist for service extension:

[image]

My Playload is;

```
    {
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "title",
            "body": "Your message Here",
            "mutable-content": "1",
            "category": "myNotificationCategory"
        }
    },
    "mediaUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.jpg",
    "mediaType": "image"
 }
```

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the "mutable-content": "1", flag outside the "alert"-object in your payload.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake here:

> Then, I have created new target with UNNotificationServiceExtension and created new bundle id "com.RichPush.app.Service-Extension" , I have also created new certificate and provision profile with above bundle for UNNotificationServiceExtension.

use **UNNotificationContentExtension** instead of **UNNotificationServiceExtension**

**after create new target, xcode will create swift (obj- c) file and storyboard interface**

I have a simple example on swift code, which load image and show on large push notification view

```
class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {


//image provided from storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any required interface initialization here.
}

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // get image url 
   // and load image here  
} 
}
```

From Apple doc:

> UNNotificationServiceExtension
>   Modifies the content of remote notifications before they are delivered to the user.

and

> UNNotificationContentExtension
>   Presents a custom interface for a delivered local or remote notification.

Comment: You don't need UNNotificationContentExtension if you just want to show an image in notification. UNNotificationContentExtension is used to provide custom interface for Notification (not the preview though).

Answer (score 0):

Your notification payload should be like this:

```
   aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = Testing;
            title = Dining;
        };
        badge = 1;
        "content-available" = 1;
        "mutable-content" = 1;
        sound = "Bleep-Sound.wav";
    };

}
```

Content-available and mutable-content should be outside the alert and also you should add the badge count too....