# How do I change firebase push notifications content in IOS 9?

Tags: swift, firebase, notifications, ios9, push

I know already how to do it in IOS 10 by use of Push notification Service, but in ios 9 it is not supported. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check this my payload content for `Rich notification`

```
{
"to": "Your_FCM_ID",
"data": {
    "image": "Anyimage URL",
    "mediaType": “JPG”,
    "type": "If_you_have_different_type_of_rich_notification"
},
"notification": {
    "body": "Body",
    "sound": "default",
    "title": "Your_title"
},
"content_available": true,
"mutable_content": true
}
```

[Check this link for the more different type of payload content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727881/3589771).

[Make sure do you have correct format code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845900/display-image-in-notification-bar-with-remote-notificationrich-media-push-notif)

[Get reference info to implement Rich notification](http://amro.co/implementing-rich-notifications-in-ios-10)