# Displaying Image Push Notification in notification bar Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, richpush

I am already implemented the normal push notification in ios using firebase and its working fine. Recently I have seen that rich push notification is introduced from iOS 10 ownwards.
I am trying to implement it in Objective C using firebase push notification.
but i am not  able to customize the notification appearance in the notification bar.

1. How can i customize the Appearance to implement images in the notification bar

Comment: Maybe is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839171/how-to-display-image-in-ios-push-notification

Comment: @trungduc thanks for your response. but i already seen that solution which is written in swift. i am looking for a solution in Objective C. if you can help me out please answer me a solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an Objective-C answer on the post. Did you check it?

Comment: You can check out this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673707/ios-10-rich-media-push-notification-media-attachment-in-objective-c

Comment: @Sibin francis : Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845900/display-image-in-notification-bar-with-remote-notificationrich-media-push-notif